# Google Maps API v3 Noop Algorithm (MarkerClusterer) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to render ~2000 google map markers by the built-in marker clusterer algorithms. The `GridAlgorithm` and `SuperClusterAlgorithm` work fine and render the clusters but the `NoopAlgorithm`, whose expected behavior is to just render all the markers on the map without clustering, does not render any marker. There are no console errors and the map renders very quickly under the `Noop` settings compared to the other 2 functionining algorithms

I am using the npm library `"@googlemaps/markerclusterer": "^2.4.0"` for `markerclusterer` and the algorithms, and `"@react-google-maps/api": "^2.19.2"` for loading the Google Maps interface

Code:

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, LoadScriptNext } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Styles from "@/public/resources/maps.json";
import {
  GridAlgorithm,
  MarkerClusterer,
  NoopAlgorithm,
  SuperClusterAlgorithm,
} from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";

let taxiMarkers: any = [];
let markerCluster: any = null;

const libraries = ["places", "geometry"];
export let pickupRoute: any;
export let dropRoute: any;

export default function Simulation() {
  const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState<google.maps.Map>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const useGrid = () => loadTaxis(new GridAlgorithm({}));
  const useNoop = () => loadTaxis(new NoopAlgorithm({}));
  const useSuper = () => loadTaxis(new SuperClusterAlgorithm({}));

  // On map load... set location to current location
  const loadMap = useCallback(function callback(map: google.maps.Map) {
    setMapRef(map);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const currLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude
      );

      map.panTo(currLocation);
      map.setZoom(14);

      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) return;
    loadTaxis(new GridAlgorithm({}));
  }, [isLoading]);

  const loadTaxis = (algorithm: any) => {
    let newTaxi;
    clearTaxis();

    fetch("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/taxi-availability")
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        const coordinates = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
        const markers = coordinates.map((coord: number[], index: number) => {
          newTaxi = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord[1], coord[0]),
            title: (index + 1).toString(),
            icon: {
              path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
              scale: 3,
            },
            optimized: true,
          });
          taxiMarkers.push(newTaxi);
          return newTaxi;
        });
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({
          map: mapRef,
          markers: markers,
          algorithm: algorithm,
        });
      });
  };

  const clearTaxis = () => {
    if (taxiMarkers.length !== 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < taxiMarkers.length; i++) {
        taxiMarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      taxiMarkers = [];
      markerCluster?.clearMarkers();
    }
  };

  return (
    <LoadScriptNext
      googleMapsApiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY as string}
      libraries={libraries as any}
    >
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 h-screen w-screen">
        <GoogleMap
          zoom={15}
          mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          options={{
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false,
            minZoom: 3,
            styles: Styles,
          }}
          onLoad={loadMap}
        />
        <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 m-5 space-x-3">
          <button onClick={useGrid}>Grid</button>
          <button onClick={useNoop}>Noop</button>
          <button onClick={useSuper}>Super</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </LoadScriptNext>
  );
}
```

Edit: As per the official documentation (https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/public/algorithms/) that compares the algorithms, I have tried simply `new NoopAlgorithm()` without the curly braces but it still does not work. This also renders a warning in the IDE: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0`

Comment: `NoopAlgorithm` documentation for reference: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/classes/NoopAlgorithm.html

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. I thought it might be because I'm using the Google AdvancedMarkerElement class, but it doesn't look like you are. I did a little debugging and the things getting returned seem to match what [Google claims] is expected. Very curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GridAlgorithm({maxZoom: 0})` instead of `NoopAlgorithm`. Markers are not clustered at maxZoom and above.